# Please explain the race condition in this put-if-absent idiom 

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, race-condition, java.util.concurrent

Consider the following code and assume that list is an synchronized List.

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());

if(!list.contains(element)){
       list.add(element)
}
```

I know that above code fragment *needs* to be synchronized externally (guarded by a lock) to make it completely thread safe .Where does the race condition come in here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have two threads

```
A: if(!list.contains(element)){ // false
B: if(!list.contains(element)){ // false
A:     list.add(element) // add once
B:     list.add(element) // add a second time.
```

Of course the simple solution is to use a Set. e.g.

```
Set<E> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<E, Boolean>());

set.add(element);
```

Comment: i do not have a Map instance I have a List instance at my disposal . However , your answer explains the race condition correctly . Thanks.

Comment: Its Set rather than Map that you would use. But if you have a List, you have to lock the collection externally to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a lot of it. A list might be mutated while `contains` is being evaluated, by the time you reach `add` someone may have added that element and you add it again. Furthermore, without synchronization the whole thing may fall apart in bizarre ways since writes by other threads may be observed by your thread partially, out of order, or not at all.

If `contains` and `add` were atomic (synchronized) by themselves, then at least there would be one well-defined race between calls to `contains` and `add`.

Comment: they are atomic, as the list is a synchronized one.

Comment: I see. Yes, then the race is as described in the last paragraph. Another thread may have added your element while your thread is in the state of having evaluated `contains` and not yet entered `add`.

Comment: By this example you can see how it's actually counterproductive to synchronize single list operations. It's just overhead.

Comment: yes, I guess one wouldn't use a synchronized collection if all calls to it are synchronized externally

Comment: All read/write methods on an object should be synchronized to prevent the issue that I explained in my answer.  This is true if you're saving to a file, or reading/writing to memory (editing the array).

Comment: @MattWestlake But of course they should. The point is that synchronization boundaries are almost always more coarse-grained than single method calls on the list.

Comment: So I guess I'm confused on what the question is then.  We all are in agreement that the read/write process needs to be inside a synchronized block.

Answer (score 2):

Well, assume two threads perform the check and both enter the conditional statement. Then both will add the same element to the list, which is not the intended behavior. Isn't that it?

Comment: If they are running on different threads, then wouldn't the "element" be different in different threads?  You're not going to add the same element to every thread in your program, and if you did, being threadsafe wouldn't correct the issue.

Comment: if the elements are necessarily different, the issue does not arise, but this is a rather strange requirement. Note that the different object instances A and B may still be considered the same, provided A.equals(B)==true.

Comment: @MattWestlake We certainly cannot assume any such thing and it would in fact be bad in most situations to assume it since the fact may change in the future and expose a bug. If the invariant is that the list doesn't contain duplicates, it must be explicitly enforced.

Comment: If A & B were the same, then being threadsafe would only insure the record got added twice (once from A and once from B).  The race condition is still A.read B.read A.write B.write only equals what B wrote.

Comment: @MattWestlake, it depends on what you mean by "threadsafe". Such a race condition is possible even with a synchronized collection, as the author of the question correctly points out, which is why _external_ synchronization is required, meaning that the whole block that does checking and adding cannot be entered by more that one thread at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The race condition would come into play between when you get the list and re-save it (if saving to a file example).

Example: File contains A

- Thread 1 Gets A
- Thread 1 Adds B to A
- Thread 2 Gets A
- Thread 1 Saves AB to file
- Thread 2 Adds C to A
- Thread 2 Saves AC to file

Read file will contain AC and the work thread 1 did is lost

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, the race condition occurs, if `list.contains(element)` yields false and another thread would add element after that but before the call to add in the first thread.